# Vue - dynamically create divs that use e.g v-on:click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I have something like that:

```
<div v-if="dataIsLoaded" v-for="(line, index) in json.data" v-on:dblclick="edit(index)" v-html="test(index)">

</div>
```

and test(index) returns html-ish string:

`<div id=${index} v-on:click="remove(index)"></div>`

How can I make it work?

My goal is:

If dataIsLoaded == true, then foreach (line, index) in json.data perform

test(index) and return its output to that container and display it as html.

Meanwhile output from test(index) can have different functions/events associated with them defined via string (as I showed above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `v-html` here? `v-html` should really only be needed in very specific and limited situations; I don't think it applies here. The string `<div id=${index} v-on:click="remove(index)"></div>` is *not* plain HTML, it's a Vue template string, so it won't work. `v-html` is also susceptible to XSS attacks; all in all I say avoid it like the plague.

Do something like this instead:

```vue
<template v-if="dataIsLoaded">
  <div v-for="(line, index) in json.data" @dblclick="edit(index)">
    <!-- Type1 -->
    <div v-if="line.type === 'Type1'" :id="index" @click="remove(index)"></div>

    <!-- Type2 -->
    <div v-else-if="line.type === 'Type2'">...</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I've added the `type` property on each line object as a discriminator to determine which template should be used for the line.

Also I've hoisted the `v-if="dataIsLoaded"` into a `<template>` above the div because `v-if` is evaluated for each div generated by the `v-for` and the condition doesn't depend on the children so it needn't be repeated for each child (a minor optimization).

If you don't like the idea of having lots of `v-if` and `v-else-if` (a sort of "switch" statement in the template) then you can use `<component :is="...">` instead:

```vue
<div v-for="(line, index) in json.data" @dblclick="edit(index)">
  <component :is="line.type" :id="index"/>
</div>
```

```es6
import Type1 from './type1.vue'
import Type2 from './type2.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Type1,
    Type2
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, can we do that without template? It's important for me cuz I'd want to use it in cshtml file

Comment: Do you mean without `<template v-if="dataIsLoaded">`? Sure, just put the `v-if` on the `<div>` as you had originally.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with `v-html`, as the [doc states](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html)

> Updates the element’s innerHTML. Note that the contents are inserted
> as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates

A more component-thinking solution is to create a component(s) with needed behaviour and paste them as a results of `v-for`:

```
// componentWithOnClick.js
<script>
export default {
name: 'ComponentWithOnClick',
methods: {
  remove() {
    //
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div id=${index} v-on:click="remove(index)"></div>
</template>
```

and then use it in the parent file:

```
//app.js
 
import ComponentWithOnClick from './ComponentWithOnClick.vue'

 {
  components: {
ComponentWithOnClick
}
//
    <div v-if="dataIsLoaded" v-for="(line, index) in json.data" v-on:dblclick="edit(index)">
    <ComponentWithOnClick></ComponentWithOnClick>
    </div>
```